# Randomize setInterval with minimum and maximum

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```js
var myVar;    
function showDiv() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.notification').length);
  $('.notification').eq(random).fadeIn(200).delay(3000).fadeOut(200);
}
function stopFunction() {
    clearInterval(myVar);  // stop the timer
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    myVar = setInterval(showDiv, 2000);
});
```

What I try now is, to randomize `setInterval` but in a range of min 2000 and max 10000.

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gkq21ppt/

Comment: What is the problem? And what is the question?

Comment: I try to show the divs in my fiddle in a random temporal distance to each other. At the moment, each div is displayed after 2000ms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use `setTimeout` to call `showDiv` with random values between 2000 and 10000 as the time interval. This can be done in `createRandomInterval` function so that you can reuse it in `showDiv` function so that it will be executed after a random time interval the next time.

Sample:

```js
var myVar;    
function showDiv(){
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.notification').length);
  $('.notification').eq(random).fadeIn(200).delay(3000).fadeOut(200);
  createRandomInterval();
}

function createRandomInterval(){
  setTimeout(showDiv, 2000+ Math.random() * 8000);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    createRandomInterval();
});
```

```css
.notification {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: none;/* hide initially so that fadIn() fadeOut() will work
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first" class="notification">first</div>
<div id="second" class="notification">second</div>
<div id="third" class="notification">third</div>
<div id="fouth" class="notification">fourth</div>
<div id="fifth" class="notification">fifth</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the interval of a `setInterval` function, here is how you can achieve this using `setTimeout`. (Note: I have removed your 3000ms delay)

```
var myVar;    
function showDiv(){
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.notification').length);
  $('.notification').eq(random).fadeIn(200);
  setTimeout(function () {
      $('.notification').eq(random).fadeOut(200);
      setTimeout( showDiv, 300);
  }, 2000 + Math.random() * 8000);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    showDiv();
});
```

PS: [updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/2dfubuLa/)

Comment: thank you. but now each div is shown after another - in no case two divs were shown at the same time. and the time they were shown randomized now, or do I see it wrong?

Comment: I might have understood your requirement wrong. Do you want more than one div to be shown at the same time?

Comment: Ah sorry, maybe my bad. Yes, each div should be displayed for 3 seconds fixed. But the temporal distance between show/delay/hide of each div should be randomize between 2 and 10 seconds. So it could happen, that 2 divs were shown at the same time - depending on the random delay I am look for, between each show/delay/hide of the div.

Comment: Great, in that case I feel Chirag's answer gives the desired solution.